# Publish multiple projects - AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Sure this will be an easy one - but when creating a pipeline for a solution that includes 2 projects, one with and without wwwroot only the web project gets published.  How do we publish all projects?

Answer (score 0):

Normally we have at least two directions:

1. Create multiple pipelines (two CI pipelines or two CI and two CD pipelines), one for `ProjectA` and the other for `ProjectB`.
2. Create one pipeline with multiple publish steps. So you may have two Publish tasks in same pipeline, one to publish `ProjectA` and the other to publish `ProjectB`.

But since it's unclear the project type of your projects, and which task do you use the 'Publish', you may get help help from these tips:

1. If the publish you mean is Publish Artifact, check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47864604/10910450).
2. If the Publish you mean is to deploy the projects to something like Azure App Service, also you're using the `Azure App Service Deploy task`:

   You can copy the ProjectA and ProjectB's outputs to same path, and set the value of `PackageOrFolder` to that path. (If the two projects have dependency relationship, so you may need to publish two projects together to same path?)

   Or just use two Publish tasks. Use the Publish task you used to use for publishing the web project. To publish the non-web project, you may need a different `publish` task? (Not sure about the project type and what place you want to publish to, I'm not sure about the task you should use).